# Katalon - get the no of rows in excel

Tags: groovy, katalon-studio

Create a Test data in the Data Files section, and get the values during the runtime of my test script, below is my code

```
TestData data = findTestData('Advanced Search')
data.changeSheet('RecordCount')
for (int excelRow : (1..5)) {
    selectQuery0 = data.getValue('Full Text Query', excelRow)
    applicationFullTextQuery.add(selectQuery0)
    selectQuery1 = data.getValue('Db Query', excelRow)
    dbQuery.add(selectQuery1)   
}
```

from the above one i have hardcoded the row count as `5`, its working perfectly

But I need to find out/get the no of rows in the excel sheet and apply the count in that for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use `getRowNumbers()` method:

```
TestData data = findTestData('Advanced Search')
data.changeSheet('RecordCount')
def n = data.getRowNumbers()
for (int excelRow : (1..n)) {
    selectQuery0 = data.getValue('Full Text Query', excelRow)
    applicationFullTextQuery.add(selectQuery0)
    selectQuery1 = data.getValue('Db Query', excelRow)
    dbQuery.add(selectQuery1)   
}
```

Comment: Getting null pointer exceptionjava.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.kms.katalon.core.testdata.reader.SheetPOI.getRowNumbers(SheetPOI.java:296)

Comment: Thanks for your help, got the answer and post the answer

Comment: @Prabu I've checked your answer. It is basically the same thing as this answer. The SO way of doing things would be to accept this answer, not giving another answer with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

```
TestData data = findTestData('Advanced Search')

data.changeSheet('RecordCount')

for (int excelRow : (1..data.getRowNumbers())) {
    selectQuery0 = data.getValue('Full Text Query', excelRow)

    applicationFullTextQuery.add(selectQuery0)

    selectQuery1 = data.getValue('Db Query', excelRow)

    dbQuery.add(selectQuery1)
}
```